# when do we use scope resolution operator before new ( ::new)?

Tags: c++, c++11, scope-resolution

I came across a code where scope resolution operator is placed before **new**. when do we use it. what is the meaning of it. Please anybody can explain ?

Comment: Do you know what it does in other contexts? (If not, why not?) Do you have an expectation that it should mean something else for `new`? (If so, why?) <--- answering these will make your question great again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`::new` is the explicit global operator.  This is as opposed to the various class-scoped operators `new` which may be defined.  For example, if I define an `operator new` inside `myclass`, and then in that same class I want to use the global one, I would say `::new`, whereas if I said `new` I would get the class-specific function I defined.

I might also use `::new` in generic template code where I am not sure what type I might be allocating, but want to make sure I do not use any class-specific allocator (for example I might need to pass the result to some API which will use global `::delete` on it).

Here's a big list of all possible operators `new` for reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new

Comment: Placement new deserves a point of mention; that is my most common use of `::new`.